# ASP.NET WebAPI 2 Versioning POST with id

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-routing, aspnet-api-versioning

I'm trying to implement the 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning' nuget in an existing productive WebAPI 2 application to support new designed 'v2' controllers.

So far everything works fine with the most controllers but now I ran into trouble with some POST controllers.

Sample code:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ApplicationApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/version")]
    public class VersionController : ApiController
    {
        //Works
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(true);
        }

        //Throws  HTTP 405 - The requested resource with API version '1.0' does not support HTTP method 'POST'.
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(int id, [FromBody]dynamic value)
        {
            return Ok(true);
        }

        //Works
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
        {
            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
}
```

All POST methods without the additional {id} work. But since we have a huge amount old clients for a long time I've to keep the old version up and running and it is not an option to remove the {id} in the old controllers. In the new controllers there is no need for the {id}.

WebAPI config

```
var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
{
    ConstraintMap =
    {
        ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint )
    }
};
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

config.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to workaround this?

Comment: Can you clarify which of those two Post methods is v2? What is the request URL like when you get 405 error?

Comment: This question is not about API versioning. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The problem has nothing to do with versioning.*

The reason for methods with `id` parameter not working is you have **conflict routes**:

```
[Route("api/version")]
```

and

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

For controller called `Version` with `Route("api/version")` attribute, you can only have either attribute routing, **OR** conventional routing (MVC / WebAPI routing), but you can't have both.

In your case, the attribute routing overrides the MVC one, so `api/version/{id}` does not exist any more. But `api/version?id` still works, because it is addressed by attribute routing.

**To fix that problem**, you can change your attribute routing on your controller to `RoutePrefix` instead of `Route`, and use `Route` with relative path on each action if necessary.

*necessary* means you have routes that cannot be addressed by conventional routing.

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix("api/version")]
public class VersionController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] dynamic value)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(int id, [FromBody] dynamic value)
    {
        return Ok(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you awareness of my answer, I think your answer is more descriptive, my eye did not catch the route part. I removed my answer. good job :)

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ thanks but there's really no need to remove your answer, instead, you could update it. You answer provides other helpful / useful information than mine, and I think it's also good for people to read.

Comment: This is a workable solution, but it also highlights how mixing routing styles can get you in trouble (and make you go cross-eyed). I strongly advise **against** mixing styles. Choose either _Direct Routing_ (aka _Attribute Routing_) or _Convention-Based Routing_.

Comment: Small point of order @weichch, MVC is not involved here at all. While they _look_ the same, routing is different in all implementation aspects. This is denoted by `Routes.MapRoute` versus `Routes.MapHttpRoute`. `RoutePrefix` and `Route` use the same attribute name, but are in different namespaces for MVC versus Web API. Most Web API types have a the `Http` prefix (ex: `IActionResult` vs `IHttpActionResult`).

Comment: @ChrisMartinez Thanks for advice. I revised the answer to use *conventional routing*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have 2 post methods, and the api does not know how to identify/generate resource name.

What you need to do is adding a customized resource name of duplicated method name.

So if we take your example for instance, you can added resource to the one that throw exception and leave the other one, or give them both unique resource name.

For example some thing like `[HttpPost("id")]`.

To confirm this I have made a test project with your code, for this I used swagger and it fails. Now when I added `id` to one of the post methods like this:

```
[HttpPost("id")]
public IActionResult Post(int id, [FromBody]dynamic value)
{
    return Ok(true);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
{
    return Ok(true);
}
```

Then it works with following output:

[image]

**Addition to main answer**
In your code you are allowing taking parameter by adding `int id` in your method

```
 Post(int id, [FromBody]dynamic value)
```

If you really don't want to use parameter then you can pass you customized object class and do some thing like, with out testing it:

```
 Post([FromBody]MyCustomObjectClass data)
```

and you `MyCustomerObjectClass`:

```
class MyCustomObjectClass {
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}
```

than you do not need 2 post methods, you can have only one, and Id can be optional.

And just not to confuse you. It is my bad I have used id in post like `[HttpPost("id")]` as name convention, it has no relation to your method Id parameter. `id` in this case is just a name of resource, it has no influence on actions. so you can call it what ever fits your logic `[HttpPost("post1")]` and `[HttpPost("post2")]`.

One last advice, it is fine to use dynamic for testing and fire up the api in short time, but I would always use static type object.

I would strongly recommend having look at [this](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/).

Comment: The HttpPost attribute does not support parameter

Comment: check my addition to the answer.

Comment: This answer is only partially correct. MVC **can** figure out `Post` methods with different parameters. The reason it cannot in this particular case, is the OP's controller name is the same as what specified by attribute routing. The attribute route overrides the `{controller}/{id}` route.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class VersionController : ApiController
{
    //Works
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/version")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }

    //Throws  HTTP 405 - The requested resource with API version '1.0' does not support HTTP method 'POST'.
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/version/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }

    //Works
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/version")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
}
```

OR

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix("api/version/")]
public class VersionController : ApiController
{
    //Works
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }

    //Throws  HTTP 405 - The requested resource with API version '1.0' does not support HTTP method 'POST'.
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }

    //Works
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
    {
        return Ok(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave the bounty to weichch cause his answer points to the same and was a bit earlier.